# How to override mui nested component styles in a theme?

Tags: material-ui, nested, styles, overriding, themes

I created a [mui](https://mui.com/) DataGrid with [editable](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/) cells.  When in edit mode, the input's padding is `0 16px` by default as seen by this style that mui generated:

```
.css-jqsvr8-MuiInputBase-root-MuiDataGrid-editInputCell input {
  padding: 0 16px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I'd like to ***override the padding above to `0 1px` inside the theme*** I created for my DataGrid:

```
const theme = createTheme({   
    components: {
        MuiDataGrid: {
            styleOverrides: {
                cell: {
                    padding: "0 1px",   // MuiDataGrid-cell default is "0 10px"
                },
        . . .
}
```

I'm at a loss for how to specify a styleOverrides for the `MuiInputBase-root-MuiDataGrid-editInputCell` above.  It was straightforward changing the normal `cell` padding.

I've read [overriding nested component styles](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-nested-component-styles) but still don't know how to specify overriding this in my `theme`.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippets

```
MuiDataGrid: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {          
          '& .MuiDataGrid-cell, & .MuiDataGrid-cell--editing': {
            //Your CSS goes here
          },       
          },
      },
    },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

select the class `.MuiDataGrid-editInputCell input`.

See https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#classes

```js
    <DataGrid
      sx={{
        '& .MuiDataGrid-editInputCell input': {
          padding: '0 1px',
        },
      }}
    />
```